# Google Direct Download Link File Type

Tags: download, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

Is there a way to tell what type of file a google downloadlink will produce? This type of link doesn't tell me anything about the file type (.mov? .png? .jpg?)

(link below is an example)

`https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=2D-99h4-CLMNPO!1234567&export=download`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the file is a Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, etc... that has a special link, e.g. `https://docs.google.com/document/d/FILE-ID`, the rest of the file types are just bundled as a generic link like `https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILE-ID`.

You can view the file type before downloading by using View Mode:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILE_ID/view
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `mimeType` property of the file.

See https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files